# How the view controller should access database using MVC

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

I know this question is already asked earlier also but i did not found any thing much useful. so asking again. I want to use the MVC architecture in accessing database from view controller. Till now the practice i was following, just creating database methods in delegate and access in view controller itself. But now i need to follow MVC pattern only as per company.
I have not found any proper tutorial to follow except apple website. I want some other where everything is described in detail and simple language to understand.
Please guide for above.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you is to use `Core Data`.
You can find a great tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) and there are many others tutorials about `Core Data` through the web.

Using `Core Data` you can access and modify your data base in every class on your app and in every view controllers using the `manageObjectContext`.